# Como arrastar alguns objetos e formulários no VBA/Excel e impedir o arrasto de outros?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formulário, vba, objetos

Estou com dificuldades ao tentar controlar o "arrastar formulários" e "arrastar objetos" no VBA/Excel.

Por exemplo: tenho o formulário principal que não quero que seja movido, um segundo formulário é chamado a partir do principal e pode ser movido, e tenho certos objetos que preciso mover nele (imagens, p. ex.), e depois quero voltar ao formulário principal.

Como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para proibir o arrastar, cole no seu código do formulário

> Private Sub UserForm_Layout() Me.Move 350, 282 End Sub